# Flink RichParallelSourceFunction - close() vs cancel()

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am implementing a RichParallelSourceFunction which reads files over SFTP. RichParallelSourceFunction inherits cancel() from SourceFunction and close() from RichFunction(). As far as I understand it, both cancel() and close() are invoked before the source is teared down. So in both of them I have to add logic for stopping the endless loop which reads files.

When I set the parallelism of the source to 1 and I run the Flink job from the IDE, Flink runtime invokes stop() right after it invokes start() and the whole job is stopped. I didn't expect this.

When I set the parallelism of the source to 1 and I run the Flink job in a cluster, the job runs as usual.
If I leave the parallelism of the source to the default (in my case 4), the job runs as usual.

Using Flink 1.7.

```java
public class SftpSource<TYPE_OF_RECORD>
    extends RichParallelSourceFunction<TYPE_OF_RECORD>
{
    private final SftpConnection mConnection;
    private boolean mSourceIsRunning;

    @Override 
    public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception
    {
        mConnection.open();
    }

    @Override 
    public void close()
    {
        mSourceIsRunning = false;
    }


    @Override
    public void run(SourceContext<TYPE_OF_RECORD> aContext)
    {
        while (mSourceIsRunning)
        {
            synchronized ( aContext.getCheckpointLock() )
            {
                // use mConnection
                // aContext.collect() ...
            }

            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ie)
            {
                mLogger.warn("Thread error: {}", ie.getMessage() );
            }
        }

        mConnection.close();
    }


    @Override
    public void cancel()
    {
        mSourceIsRunning = false;
    }
}
```

So I have workarounds and the question is more about the theory. Why is close() invoked if parallelism is 1 and the job is run from the IDE (i.e. from the command line)?
Also, do close() and cancel() do the same in a RichParallelSourceFunction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is close() invoked if parallelism is 1 and the job is run from the
>   IDE.

`close` is called after the last call to the main working methods (e.g. map or join). This method can be used for clean up work.
It will be called independent of the number defined in parallelism.

> Also, do close() and cancel() do the same in a RichParallelSourceFunction?

They aren't the same thing, take a look at how it's described.

```
Cancels the source. Most sources will have a while loop inside the run(SourceContext) method. The implementation needs to ensure that the source will break out of that loop after this method is called.
```

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/functions/source/SourceFunction.html#cancel--

The following link may help you to understand the task lifecycle:
https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/internals/task_lifecycle.html#operator-lifecycle-in-a-nutshell

Comment: Choosing this because:
- the explanation about close() + the comparison of close() and cancel() + the input from morsik answer the difference between close() and cancel()
-  the link about the task lifecycle gives more to the answer and maybe it helped me find my bug

Answer (score 1):

I think javadocs are more than self-explanatory:

```
Gracefully Stopping Functions
Functions may additionally implement the {@link org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.StoppableFunction} interface. "Stopping" a function, in contrast to "canceling" means a graceful exit that leaves the state and the emitted elements in a consistent state.
```

-- [SourceFunction.cancel](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/functions/source/SourceFunction.html#cancel--)

```
Cancels the source. Most sources will have a while loop inside the run(SourceContext) method. The implementation needs to ensure that the source will break out of that loop after this method is called.
A typical pattern is to have an "volatile boolean isRunning" flag that is set to false in this method. That flag is checked in the loop condition.

When a source is canceled, the executing thread will also be interrupted (via Thread.interrupt()). The interruption happens strictly after this method has been called, so any interruption handler can rely on the fact that this method has completed. It is good practice to make any flags altered by this method "volatile", in order to guarantee the visibility of the effects of this method to any interruption handler.
```

-- [SourceContext.close](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/functions/source/SourceFunction.SourceContext.html#close--)

```
This method is called by the system to shut down the context.
```

**Note**, you can cancel SourceFunction, but stop SourceContext

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of cancel(). Combined with the input from Ricardo Alvaro Lohmann, it gives the answer about the difference between close() and cancel().

Answer (score 0):

I found a bug in my code. Here is the fix

```
public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception
{
    mConnection.open();
    mSourceIsRunning = true;
}
```

Now close() is not invoked until I decide to stop the workflow in which case first is invoked cancel() and then close(). I am still wondering how did parallelism affect the behaviour.